# Is it possible to bundle up default project maven dependencies together to have a starter kit to achieve uniformity across Java projects?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

We are working with multiple team members and would like to have a standard pom.xml in Java. Question is, is it possible to bundle up common dependancies as one, then when pulled into a project, it brings uniformity?

Anyone?

Different team members have been using different dependancies, we would like to have a standard starter kit.

Comment: Maven 'Bill of Materials' (BoM) was created exactly for this purpose - https://reflectoring.io/maven-bom/

Comment: Look at having a parent pom. A BoM is great for dependencies, but you will probably also want some standard plugin configuration.

Comment: I would discourage you to share parent poms across different teams: sooner or later that turns every child project's pom into endless list of overrides. It is more preferable to manage set of maven archetypes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Andrey, looks like maven archetypes is what am looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).